# issue with custom date translation - wp

Tags: wordpress, date, translate

I am using this code in Wordpress to display a **custom** date. It works fine. The dates are displayed in English.

Now I need the dates to be translated from English to my site's base local language (Italian). I tried using  **date_i18n()** for example and indeed it returns results in Italian, but it ignored my custom date and displayed the current date instead, so I removed it.

I am not sure how to apply date_i18n() to this script and I would appreciate any other solution.

```
        <?php 
            if(get_field('data_evento')){
                $datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', get_field('data_evento'));
                $data_giorno = $datetime->format( 'D');
                $data_giorno_num = $datetime->format('d');
                $data_mese = $datetime->format('M');            
        } ?>
        
        <div class="date-postit">
            <span class="data_giorno"><?php echo $data_giorno; ?></span><br>
            <span class="data_giorno_num"><?php echo $data_giorno_num; ?></span><br>
            <span class="data_mese"><?php echo $data_mese; ?></span>        
        </div>
```

Here in an example of how I used date_i18n:

```
$unixtimestamp = strtotime( get_field('data_evento') );
echo date_i18n( "l d F, Y", $unixtimestamp );
```

I could not get it to return my custom date.

Comment: Can you please show how you used `date_i18n()`? You need to provide a format and Unix timestamp as the arguments to this function.

Comment: This is how I tried:

`$unixtimestamp = strtotime( get_field('data_evento') );
echo date_i18n( "l d F, Y", $unixtimestamp );
`

Answer (score 0):

Solved by myself. Thanks anyway, I post the solution hoping this is useful for someone other.

```
        <?php 
            if(get_field('data_evento')){
                $datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', get_field('data_evento'));
        } ?>
        <div class="date-postit">
            <span class="data_giorno_txt"><?php echo date_i18n( 'D', strtotime(date_format($datetime, 'D'))); ?></span><br>
            <span class="data_giorno_num"><?php echo date_i18n( 'd', strtotime(date_format($datetime, 'd'))); ?></span><br>
            <span class="data_mese"><?php echo date_i18n( 'M', strtotime(date_format($datetime, 'M'))); ?></span><br>
                
        </div>
```